# Hadoop Streaming with very large size of stdout

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have two programs for Hadoop streaming.

```
  mapper (produces <k, v> pair)
  reducer
```

Of course, `<k, v>` pairs are emitted to `stdout`.

My question is

if `v` in `<k, v>` is very large, does it run on hadoop efficiently?

I guess `v` emitted by mapper will be 1G or more (sometimes more than 4G).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think such sizes of Value will cause a problem, because it is problematic to manipulate them in memory. If you indeed need such a huge values, you can put them into the HDFS and to make V to be a name of the file. The problem you should consider in this case is fact that this approach is no longer functional - you have side effect, for example from the failed mapper.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Of course, pair is emitted to stdout"?

Do you mean to say that the number of key value pairs is very large as in ? If yes, then hadoop handles this efficiently.

If you mean to sat that the size of v is very large. So, for a given key the value emitted is 1 to 4 GB or even more. First of all what kind of application are you running to generate the values so large. Is it possible to break up keys?

Back to the main point: Hadoop would not be very efficient or not. Depends on the use case. 
In most of the cases it would be highly inefficient.